# Changing cordova barcode scanner default message

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using cordova barcodescanner for my hybrid app development and i am very concern about the default message of the barcode scanner which says:  **"Place a barcode inside the viewfinder rectangle to scan it."**

How could i change the default message? I am expecting similar to this:
NgCordova:
      $cordovaBarcodeScanner
          .scan()
          .title('Please scan here') //something like this
          .then(function(barcodeData) {
            // Success! Barcode data is here
          }, function(error) {
            // An error occurred
          });

From cordova plugins: But i dunno how to use it in cordovaBarcodeScanner

```
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
      function (result) {

      }, 
      function (error) {
          alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
      },
      {
          // how can i use this in above?
          "prompt" : "Place a barcode inside the scan area", 
      }
   );
```

Comment: @JoeClay but cordova plugin does have the functionality. I just dunno how to use it in ngCordova. So do you mean that something that cordova plugin have might not be available in ngCordova?

Answer (score 0):

To implement barcode-scanner follow this steps.

step 1: install this `cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.git` into your project.

step 2: Implement this code in you js file

```
$cordovaBarcodeScanner
      .scan()
      .then(function(barcodeData) {
        // Success! Barcode data is here
      }, function(error) {
        // An error occurred
      });


    // NOTE: encoding not functioning yet
    $cordovaBarcodeScanner
      .encode(BarcodeScanner.Encode.TEXT_TYPE, "http://www.nytimes.com")
      .then(function(success) {
        // Success!
      }, function(error) {
        // An error occurred
      });

  },
```

To know more about ngCordova barcodescanner look this [website](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/barcodeScanner/).

Here is a tutorial for more information [nicrobay barcode scanner](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/09/implement-barcode-scanner-using-ionic-framework/).

and the message you revive as alert is what are receiving from the back end.

Comment: So how can i change the text?

Comment: after scanning the text or URL you receive is sent from back end i am not familiar with that but i am sure you should see in back end for the text you receive from the bar-code.